# multiple Threads read to the same table in database by using the same connection in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-data-jpa

I have defined three transaction in which select operations and SELECT operations are happening on the different parameter passed . I try to invoke this method concurrently . I am get an error:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
    Aug 25, 2020 @ 12:16:39.000 2020-08-25 06:46:39.388 ERROR 1 --- [o-9003-exec-630] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Hikari - Connection is not available, request timed out after 60000ms.
```

And sometimes

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

I am new to java. Please guide me to solve this issue. Do I need to write multithreading to access number of resources or configuration issue?

```
hikari:
                    poolName: Hikari
                    autoCommit: false
                    minimumIdle: 5
                    connectionTimeout: 60000
                    maximumPoolSize: 80
                    idleTimeout: 60000
                    maxLifetime: 240000
                    leakDetectionThreshold: 300000
```

Comment: Looks like the psql's connections were exhausted, how many connections did you make ？Can you show code that creates connections?

Comment: Repeat after me: one connection - one thread - one transaction - ...

Answer (score 4):

> Multiple Threads read to the same table in database by using the same connection in java?

This is generally speaking not going to work.  The JDBC API types `Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet` and so on are not generally thread-safe<sup>1</sup>.  You should not try to use on instance in multiple threads.

If you want to avoid having multiple connections open the normal approach is to use a JDBC connection pool to manage the connections.  When a thread needs to talk to the database, it gets a connection from the pool.  When it has finished talking to the database, it releases it back to the pool.

In the PostgreSQL / Hikari case:

- For PostgreSQL - ["Using the driver in a multi-threaded or a servlet environment"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/jdbc-thread.html)
- For Hikari - the `getConnection()` call is thread-safe, but I couldn't find anything that explicitly talked about the thread-safety of the connection object when shared by multiple threads.

---

<sup>1 - I have seen it stated that a spec compliant JDBC driver should be thread-safe, but I could not see where the JDBC spec actually requires this to be so.  But even assuming that it does say that somewhere, the threads sharing a connection would need to coordinate very carefully to avoid things like one thread causing another thread's resultset to "spontaneously" close.</sup>